# Simulate projector with depth of field using spotlight

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, depth-of-field

I am quite new to Blender and trying to accurately simulate a projector with an image texture.
Currently I simulate the projector using a spotlight with the following shader:[image]

which works well enough so far. A real projector, however, have depth of field and I have so far been unable to figure out how to simulate depth of field using a spotlight. Any suggestions on how to blur parts of the image texture based on a focus distance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess the quick way I would solve this is to render a sequence from the projector point of view with DoF on, and then insert that image sequence as the texture being projected.

Comment: But... having installed tons of projectors, usually you're projecting on a plane that gives you nearly perfect focus on the screen, and in situations where that's not possible, modern projectors have the ability to lens shift which adjusts the projector's optics physically to avoid focus problems.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I’m trying to simulate a structured light scanner where unfortunately the dof of the projector will be very relevant. I’m not sure how your first point would work if the projector pattern was projected on to an object with its own texture?

Comment: This is just a guess but Add Shader the emission over the top of the existing texture